# How to enable sending keyboard signals while in SSH?

Tags: keyboard, terminal, macos, signal

When I use a keyboard plugged into the pi directly, I can send signals using `ctrl+T` / `^T` to get messages from ongoing commands in terminal.

When I'm logged in via SSH on my mac, I seem to lose this functionality, because `ctrl+T` simply prints `^T` without any of the goodies.

I'm aware there's a difference between mac/BSD and Linux keybindings. I'm told that on Linux, the equivalent is sending `SIGUSR1`. However, when I've got a long running command on the Pi and in a separate window I do

```
kill -s SIGUSR1 <pid>
```

I don't get the goodies I want. Is there a way I can get the goodies from sending `^T` on mac but on the Pi and other Linux distros?

Comment: maybe you can see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/394100/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-z-not-working-in-terminal) "If you are using a MAC keyboard Command+dot/period should be equivalent to Ctrl+C for break"

Answer (score 2):

The signal `SIGUSR1` is not among the signals that can be generated by the keyboard. For the signals that can be generated, see the manual page of `stty` or the output of `stty -a`.

That means that the signal is generated by the particular terminal emulator and sent to the program.

If you don't get the expected output from sending `SIGUSR1`, then the program probably doesn't react to that signal in the way you expect. Maybe you should verify that it is actually `SIGUSR1` that causes the effect you want to achieve.